# Which stars do I have to use to join with a line to draw constellation?

Tags: constellations

I continue working on a planetarium software and I want to draw the lines that the draw the constellation's figure:

[image]

Is there a catalogue or something similar with the stars which are the vertex of the figure?

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/stars-in-constellation-patterns-by-catalogue-number